How to import class from one script into another?
For example i have in scriptA.gd class:
class Effect:
    var name: String
    var stat: String
    var value
    
    func _init(name: String, stat: String, value) -> void:
        self.name = name
        self.stat = stat
        self.value = value

And i want to reuse this class in scriptB.gd without just rewriting it in scriptB.gd

By adding class_name _____ you can reference this class:
class_name Effect 

class Effect:
    var name: String
    var stat: String
    var value
    
    func _init(name: String, stat: String, value) -> void:
        self.name = name
        self.stat = stat
        self.value = value



Instantiating an object of the class
Effect.new("name", "some value")


Extending Effect / creating subclasses
extends Effect
class_name FrostEffect

class FrostEffect:
     # Apply some kind of slow and call super._init()



If you just want to re-use some pure functions or whatever, you can use the static keyword to make it callable from anywhere
class_name Effects
static var all = {
    "slow": FrostEffect.new("Slow", "Slows you")
}

To be used anywhere like Effects.all.slow

Or if you want a singleton class; a class that exists once and can be referenced from anywhere, you can use the AutoLoad feature which you configure from the GUI.
Add Effect to your AutoLoad list and then you will be able to reference it from anywhere with just Effect. But I am guessing what you are after is the first option of adding class_name and then instantiating it.

The solution is that scriptA.gd must be added to project globals(it becomes like singleton) and have needed class in this script.
Then in scriptB.gd just do var Effect = Singleton.Effect.
It will work, but editor wont think that its class or type but just variable
